# Playing .m3u8 file in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am able to play the HLS smooth streaming file (having extension .ism/maniest) using MediaElement and Microsoft Smooth Streaming client SDK in Windows Store App

However when set the source of MediaElement to .m3u8 file, the video is not played.

Is it possible to play .m3u8 file in Windows Store App?

Regards,

SRS

Answer (score 1):

.m3u8 file does not seem to be supported in Windows Store App.

[Supported audio and video formats (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh986969.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

HLS (m3u8) isn't supported by the platform. But you have these options:

1. create your own media source provider
2. [3ivx](http://www.3ivx.com/), a library
   that supports both Windows store apps, and windows phone 8, but they
   are really expensive (for me the offer was 7500 Australian dollars
   per app)
3. [Apptelic HLS](http://www.apptelic.com/)‏, a commerical library for Windows 8
   and windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this for months and the only solution that works is this one

http://phonesm.codeplex.com/releases/view/119845

I know it says phone but it does support windows 8.1 store apps also 
HLS is a nightmare to solve in Windows 8 apps, This option is open-source and is easy enough to implement Hope it helps you